# I am stuck in scheduling task through Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I want to schedule 10 alarm for daily to start and stop  service. But only past alarm trigger, I search a lot on google but did't get correct solution. Here is my code please check it and help me.

```
Intent start_intent,stop_intent;
List<Calendar> Calander_list;

static PendingIntent pendingIntent;

Calendar[] startCal,stopCal;
AlarmManager[] startAlarm,stopAlarm;
PendingIntent[] startIntent,stopIntent;


SharedPreferences sp;
Random rd;
Context context;
```

global  Variable sp have stored time.

```
 public Alarm_schedul(Context cont) {

    context = cont;
    rd = new Random();
    Calander_list = new ArrayList<Calendar>();

    startAlarm=new AlarmManager[5];
    stopAlarm=new AlarmManager[5];
    startCal=new Calendar[5];
    stopCal=new Calendar[5];
    startIntent=new PendingIntent[5];
    stopIntent=new PendingIntent[5];

    start_intent=new Intent(context,alarm_reciver.class);
    start_intent.putExtra("alarmtype","start");

    stop_intent=new Intent(context,alarm_reciver.class);
    stop_intent.putExtra("alarmtype","stop");

    sp = context.getSharedPreferences("salah", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    setup_calander();
    init();
}
```

Alarm_schedul(Context cont) class constructor.

```
public void setup_calander() {
    Fajar();
    Zuhar();
    Ashar();
    Magrab();
    Ishia();
}
public void Fajar()
 {

    String time = "", h = "", m = "";
    int index = 0;

    time = sp.getString("Fajar_from", "00:00");
    index = time.indexOf(":");
    h = time.substring(0, index);
    m = time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    //set up calander
    startCal[0]=Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal[0].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    startCal[0].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    startCal[0].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));
    Calander_list.add(startCal[0]);
    //====

    time = sp.getString("Fajar_to", "00:00");
    index = time.indexOf(":");
    h = time.substring(0, index);
    m = time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    stopCal[0]=Calendar.getInstance();
    stopCal[0].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    stopCal[0].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    stopCal[0].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));


}

public void Zuhar()
{
    String time="",h="",m="";
    int index=0;

    time=sp.getString("Zuhar_from", "00:00");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    startCal[1]=Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal[1].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    startCal[1].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    startCal[1].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));
    Calander_list.add(startCal[1]);

    //====
    time=sp.getString("Zuhar_to", "00:00");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    stopCal[1]=Calendar.getInstance();
    stopCal[1].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    stopCal[1].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    stopCal[1].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));

}

public void Ashar()
{

    String time="",h="",m="";
    int index=0;
    time=sp.getString("Asar_from", "no values");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    startCal[2]=Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal[2].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    startCal[2].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    startCal[2].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));
    Calander_list.add(startCal[2]);

    //====
    time=sp.getString("Asar_to", "no values");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    stopCal[2]=Calendar.getInstance();
    stopCal[2].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    stopCal[2].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    stopCal[2].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));

}

public void Magrab()
{
    String time="",h="",m="";
    int index=0;

    time=sp.getString("Magrab_from", "no values");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());

    startCal[3]=Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal[3].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    startCal[3].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    startCal[3].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));
    Calander_list.add(startCal[3]);

    //====
    time=sp.getString("Magrab_to", "no values");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    stopCal[3]=Calendar.getInstance();
    stopCal[3].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    stopCal[3].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    stopCal[3].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));
}

public void Ishia()
{
    String time="",h="",m="";
    int index=0;
    time=sp.getString("Ishia_from", "no values");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    startCal[4]=Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal[4].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    startCal[4].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    startCal[4].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));
    Calander_list.add(startCal[4]);
    //====
    time=sp.getString("Ishia_to", "no values");
    index=time.indexOf(":");
    h =time.substring(0, index);
    m=time.substring(index + 1, time.length());
    stopCal[4]=Calendar.getInstance();
    stopCal[4].setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    stopCal[4].set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(h));
    stopCal[4].set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(m));
}
```

Setup Calender

```
public void init()
{

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        startAlarm[i]= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        startIntent[i]=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,i,start_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        startAlarm[i].setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,startCal[i].getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,startIntent[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        stopAlarm[i]= (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        stopIntent[i]=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,i+5,stop_intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        stopAlarm[i].setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,stopCal[i].getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,stopIntent[i]);
    }

}
```

`init()` method use to initialize Alarm Manager.

Comment: Please explain more in detail wht is not working ? do you have error/exception logs  ?

Comment: it is working. but previous alarm managers call continuously.for example  if I set alarm at 5:00 am O clock then it is trigger continuously after 5:00am.
is it clear or not?

Comment: Basically I have alarm manager array of size 10(5 for start service at different time and 5 for stop those service after some interval).
there is separate Calender and Pending intent for each Alarm manager.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/878126/android-developer